# Random images with acf (gallery option)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gallery

Can you tell me what i need to add to make random image gallery.
Do i need to create new variable like $rand?
I'm looking for answer, but i cannot find. I created $rand = array_rand($gallery, 1);. But it's not working. Help :)

```html
<section class="gallery-section">
    <div class="container padding">
        <h2>Galeria</h2>
        <div class="gallery-container">
            <div class="row">
                    <?php 
                $images = get_field('gallery');
                
                if( $images ): ?>
                 <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    
                    <div class="image-wrapper">
                        <a class=“fancybox” rel=“gallery href="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>">
                     <img class ='img-fluid'  src="<?php echo esc_url($image ['sizes']['large']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>"  />
                    </a>
                    
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                
                
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) is used to pick one (or more) random keys from a given array. If you want to present the images of a gallery in a random order, you should use [`shuffle()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) instead:

```php
$images = get_field('gallery');
if ($images) {
    shuffle($images); // <-- Note that it modifies to original array.
    foreach($images as $image) {...}
}
```